# Nginx and iptables overlapping

Tags: nginx, iptables

I'm a little confused with nginx and iptables, I want to redirect all traffic to port 443 or port 8443 on my server,  I also have mongodb running on port 27017, by blocking it, will I be able to access the database from my node.js app (which is running on port 8443)? should I use nginx to redirect or iptables? it seems that sometimes they overlap each other. So, which one is better to handle this?

Comment: Hum could you clarify a bit ? Overlapping for what exatcly ?

Comment: pretty basic error I think but, blocking specific ports with iptables in which nginx is listening to, or e.g. [iptables is blocking nginx from being a reverse proxy for node.js](http://serverfault.com/questions/480564/iptables-is-blocking-nginx-from-being-a-reverse-proxy-for-node-js)

Comment: Don't you listen on the loopback interface for internal services ? Maybe you should precise your current setup and the relationship between each element and IP addresses in use. I don't really understand what you are trying to filter that would also be in the scope of nginx.

Comment: I guess that, simplifying my question would be, in case I want to listen to only 443 and 8443 ports should I redirect the traffic with nginx or should I redirect with iptables, or work with both at the same time? I can't think of a scenario where I use both of them to their specific aptitudes.